# ¿como auto mapear con automapper-js?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, map

estoy tratando de implementar [automapper-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-js) para mapear un un objeto .

este es el objeto que quiero mapear, me lo retorna [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/) al consultar a base de datos que es una relación de uno a muchos entre roles y users. en los modelos de [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) les declare una asociación, en el modelo de Role declare una relación hasMany con el modelo User y el modelo User delcare una relación belongsTo con Role

```
const user = {
    id: 1,
    fullName: 'Admin Root',
    email: 'admin@root.com',
    password: '$2a$10$ofcEvO0dHDh0YGWosyc3FOAK5C8IM0fwkPgITR.yibJ.ihSGEw9ie',
    request: false,
    createdAt: '2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z',
    roleId: 1,
    RoleId: 1,
    Role: {
        name: 'admin',
    },
}
```

este es el resultado que estoy buscando

```
{
    id: 1,
    Role: 'admin',
    fullName: 'Admin Root',
    email: 'admin@root.com',
    request: false,
    createdAt: '2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z',
}
```

esta es la clase que estoy implementando

```
class UserData {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0
        this.roleId = 0
        this.Role = {}
        this.fullName = ''
        this.email = ''
        this.request = 0
        this.createdAt = null
        this.updatedAt = null
    }
}
```

este es el resultado que obtengo al ejecutar

```
mapper(UserData, user)

{
    "id": 1,
    "roleId": 1,
    "Role": {
        "name": "admin"
    },
    "fullName": "Admin Root",
    "email": "admin@root.com",
    "request": 0,
    "createdAt": "2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-24T04:32:45.000Z"
}
```

que debo hacer para obtener lo que busco ??

Comment: Y porque no simplemente usar el JSON entero?, que beneficios trae "mapear" el objeto?, a mi parecer solo quieres obtener las propiedades que te interesan en un objeto aparte, lo cual no seria un mapeo, si no un filtro, muchas APIs de hecho te permiten decirles que propiedades quieres recuperar, para que asi no te devuelvan una larga lista de informacion innecesaria.

Comment: Ah por lo que veo no es una API que te da esos datos, si no una base de datos, en ese caso hay consultas que te devuelven directamente un JSON con la informacion especificada que necesitas, de hecho lo ideal siempre es que esta clase de consultas se hagan desde el backend para no tener que filtrar y acomodar informacion en el frontend.

Comment: Tal como plantea @Riven, y ya que utilizas `Sequelize`, podrías crear un método en tu modelo que te devuelva la información en el formato que especificas, luego simplemente devuelves al cliente el resultado de la llamada a dicho método. Saludos